# Expandablelistview collapses the 2nd level groups on scroll

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement a 2-level expandable list view. I found the reference for the same from here : http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84

This works fine. But as soon as i scroll the list view or i click on another group, the expanded children get collapsed.

I would like to preserve the expanded groups.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll a ListView the views are recycled and hence if you want to keep your group expanded you will need to maintain a list of the clicked groups.